# How many dungeon levels are available in Gauntlet?

Tags: gauntlet

In the original Gauntlet arcade game by Atari, how many unique dungeon levels are there?

The manual states "over a hundred", but that is imprecise and I'd like to have an explanation:

[image: Gauntlet Manual - Gameplay]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Video Game Atlas (VGMaps.com) section [Arcade - Gauntlet](https://www.vgmaps.com/Atlas/Arcade/#Gauntlet) has **125** level maps, 114 regular levels and 11 treasure levels.

A forum post documents the release progress: [Gauntlet [Arcade] - All 125 arcade boards mapped out, plus extras](https://www.vgmaps.com/forums/?topic=1785.0). It explains:

- The mappers (negative1 and rge) made up the level names.
- The maps "include all treasure levels". Browsing through the incremental progress posts, level 114 is described as the last regular level and levels 115 to 125 are the treasure levels.
- The maps do not include "variations where exits [are] moved".

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is no end, I mastered every character with just a quarter in the mid 80s.
one of the last plays was over 20hrs and the levels just repeat.